# How to speedup serverless packaging

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a serverless application in which multiple modules are considered as one serverless project, like customeradmin, productadmin. Each module deploy as separated project, what i need is each module gets too much time for packaging, Is there ay way to decrease the packaging time so i can deploy services faster.I exclude dev-dependencies aslo,or is there any way to deploy all modules parallel.

Comment: can you share more details about how do you deploy ?  deploying in parallel is certainly an option but without knowing the tools you're using, it is difficult to make a suggestions.

Comment: Assuming you are deploying to AWS Lambda (not mentioned in the question), did you consider using Lambda Layers ?  This would allow to package and deploy your runtime dependencies only once and not at every function re-deployment https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: If it's only the code that has changed you could just deploy the function `sls deploy function -f <FUNCTION_NAME>` for example which'll cut some overhead time for CloudFormation stack updates/monitoring etc. Won't really decrease your packaging time but might help none the less.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq yes i am deploying aws lambda and for that serverless webpack plugin is used.

Comment: @TomNijs I have jenkins jobs to deploy all modules of project. they currently deploying one by one. Actually we have a bash file in which all sls deploy commands are written that file runs on jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

We are not using serverless-webpack. It introduces way too many additional points of failure and configuration. Trying to KISS it.

Instead we have a set of gulp tasks that run webpack just as you would from the command line. There are also tasks that run serverless as well. We are using process.spawnSync to run those processes to ensure node's memory is managed properly (webpack was consuming all the memory).
This setup also makes it super simple to debug out build process as each step can be ran from the command line and tested independent of the rest of the steps.